# VueJS Работа с dialog и cookie

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Есть у меня проект. В нём диалоговое окно которое появляется в зависимости от записей в куки, но сама проблема в том, что это диалоговое окно не закрывает и как правильное это сделать, я что-то не могу понять. Нужна ваща помощь.

Код:

```
<v-dialog v-if="maturityConfirmation" v-model="maturityConfirmation" persistent class="elevation-0" width="500">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title class="justify-center">
      <h1>18+</h1>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <h2 class="text-md-center">Для доступа на сайт Вы должны подтвердить, что Вы достигли 18-летнего возраста.</h2>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-card-actions class="justify-center">
      <v-btn color="default" @click="setMaturityConfirmationAccepted()">Мне есть 18 лет</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
<script>
  ...
  computed: {
    maturityConfirmation() {
      return this.$store.state.maturityConfirmation;
    },
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    setMaturityConfirmationAccepted() {
      const cookieDate = new Date();
      cookieDate.setMonth(cookieDate.getMonth() + 1);
      document.cookie = `maturityConfirmation=false;expires=${cookieDate.toUTCString()}`;

      this.$store.commit('SetMaturityConfirmation', false);
    },
    getMaturityConfirmation () {
      const maturityConfirmation = document.cookie.match(/maturityConfirmation=(.+?)(;|$)/);

      this.$store.commit('SetMaturityConfirmation', maturityConfirmation === null || maturityConfirmation[1] !== 'false');
    }
  },
  created() {
    ...
    this.getMaturityConfirmation();
  },
...
</script>
```

Думаю прикладывать store не буду он обычный, переменная maturityConfirmation по умолчанию true, т.е. окно показывать.

Comment: Сделайте дополнительную проверку ```v-if="maturityConfirmation && dialogOpened"```. А dialogOpened будет отвечать за открытие-закрытие диалогового окна.

Comment: @ВикторКарев Сейчас попробую